# mysql: command not found but it is in my PATH

Tags: mysql, macos, bash, terminal

.bashrc says:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

but `mysql -u root` returns

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

but if I do `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`
everything works fine. Why isn't it search using PATH?

Thanks

Comment: If you do `echo $PATH` in a shell, do you see the changed `PATH`?  If not, I might know why.

Comment: Does you `.bashrc` `export PATH`?

Comment: @fge That's what I think is going on, I have an answer drafted that I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use:

```
export PATH=$PATH:...
```

Or add the `export PATH` statement after this statement.

The changes you are making are not surviving beyond the execution of your `.bashrc`.  Adding `export` before your assignment (or `export PATH`) later will ensure that your changes are exported to your shell's child processes.

Comment: Thanks. Also has to do source ~/.bashrc to reload the file after saving.

Comment: Unexported variables do survive beyond the execution of `.bashrc`, and $PATH is used by the shell itself so it doesn't need to be exported to work. But unexported, it would not show up in su or screen or other child processes as you mentioned.